# Inhibitors of hydration

Tags: polymers, boron-family

Superglue (Cyanoacrylate) polymerizes via hydration, and using an activator such as a borax solution speeds up that process. I need to mix these 2 without them reacting. (Or at least not noticeably.)

So, I was wondering if there are any inhibitors that can stop this reaction at least temporarily. I'm not well versed in chemistry, so if I got a concept or anything wrong with my question, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Cyanacrylate polymerisation is *initiated* by single water molecules. No "hydration" takes place whatsoever.

Comment: Googling "borax superglue" does not lead to any sensible results. Borax certainly does not act as an activator there.

Comment: Inhibitors for cyanacrylate polymerisation are drying agents, or substances that catch the active ionic end group of the growing polymeric anion and transform it into something that doesn't (or only much slower) react with cyanacrylate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [inhibitors and "stabilizers" such as acids](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5290825A/en). You might experiment with acetic acid (of course, "glacial", not as a water solution), or $\ce{FeCl3}$, which would make the polymer dark or opaque. Another inhibitor is [pyrogallol and boric acid](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4182823A/en), which likely would be compatible borates.

The reference above also cautions that an *excess* of inhibitor can prevent polymerization, so test various inhibitors and various concentrations to see what works for your intended use.

If you do find a good inhibitor, to help others, please add an answer here or at least a comment on what worked in that application.